Swift Data cascading in one to many to many relationship
I have a one to many to many relationship in SwiftData model. My Workout model has a list of EInfo and EInfo has a list of ESet. My problem arises when I try to delete an ESet model from a EInfo. Looking at the DB Browser I see that swiftdata automatically assigns the workout variable in the EInfo model, however it does not do the same for ESet. So when I try to delete ESet using
eInfo.sets.removeFirst()

for example, it removes it from the list but the instance of that ESet is still stored in the storage.
@Model
class Workout {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var date: Date
    var endDate: Date
    var name : String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var exercises: [EInfo]
    var isFinished: Bool
    var orders: [Int]
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), date: Date = Date.now, endDate: Date = Date.now, name: String = "New Workout", exercises: [EInfo] = [], isFinished: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.exercises = exercises
        self.isFinished = isFinished
        self.orders = []
        self.endDate = endDate
    }
    func orderedExercises() -> [EInfo] {
        return exercises.sorted(by: { $0.index < $1.index })
    }
    func updateWithTemplate(template : WorkoutTemplate) {
        for exercise in template.exercises {
            var sets : [ESet] = []
            for _ in 0..<exercise.numberOfSets {
                let set = ESet(index: sets.count, done: false)
                sets.append(set)
            }
            self.addExercise(exerciseID: exercise.exerciseID)
            self.exercises.first(where: {$0.exerciseID == exercise.exerciseID})?.sets = sets
        }
    }
}
@Model
class EInfo {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var exerciseID: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var sets: [ESet]
    var index : Int
    var workout: Workout? = nil
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), exerciseID: String = "", sets: [ESet] = [ESet()], index : Int = 0) {
        self.id = id
        self.exerciseID = exerciseID
        self.sets = sets
        self.index = index
    }
    func isCompleted()->Bool{
        return sets.allSatisfy { $0.done } && sets.count > 0
    }
}

@Model
class ESet {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var index: Int
    var weight: Double
    var exercise: EInfo? = nil
    var weight_ : Double{
        get {weight}
        set {weight = newValue}
    }
    var reps: Int
    var done: Bool = false
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), index: Int = 0, weight: Double = 0, reps: Int = 0, done: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.index = index
        self.weight = weight
        self.reps = reps
        self.done = done
    }
    
}

Usage in code
.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    var count = 0
                    for index in indexSet{
                        for set in exerciseInfo.sets.sorted(by: {$0.index < $1.index}){
                            if count==index{
                                exerciseInfo.sets.removeAll(where: {$0.id == set.id})
                            }
                            count+=1
                        }
                    }
                   
                })
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                SetRowView(index: -1, set: ESet())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        let set = ESet(index: exerciseInfo.sets.count, done: false)
                        exerciseInfo.sets.append(set)
                    }

I have tried specifying the inverse relationship and that also results in the same thing.
Any help is appreciated!

Deleting an object from a relationship is not the same thing as deleting it from the storage (database), the first is actually an update of the object.
So to completely delete an object you need to do both, remove it from the relationship and delete it.
exerciseInfo.sets.removeAll(where: {$0.id == set.id})
modelContext.delete(set)

Also beware that cascading delete is something different, it means that when you delete an object SwiftData will automatically delete all related objects.
You can test this by deleting an EInfo object and check the storage, not only will the EInfo object be gone but also all ESet objects belonging to that EInfo objects are now deleted.

Ah youre right, when I delete EInfo or ESet using context.delete it works. My other issue is that when I create an ESet object and add it to the EInfo.sets array the ESet.exercise variable does not get updated with a reference to the parent (EInfo).
First I thought maybe inserting an object to the array doesnt automatically define a relationship but when I add an EInfo to a Workout object like this it correctly adds a reference to the parent.

I have answered your original question so please respect that and post a separate question if you have another issue.
